# Getting both computer and user objects from inside security group via powershell

Tags: powershell

I can get the user accounts in the group with the following script. But I want to get both computer object and user object in some groups. how can I do it?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'TST*'"
ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
  Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group  | 
    Get-ADUser -Properties samaccountname,mail,AccountExpires,manager,employeeid,employeetype | 
    Select-Object samaccountname,mail,employeeid,employeetype,@{l="expiration_date";e={ accountExpiresToString($_.AccountExpires)}},@{n=”Manager Name”;e={(Get-ADuser -identity $_.Manager -properties displayname).DisplayName}} | 
   Export-CSV -Path "C:tmp\$($group.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: How is "accordingly"? Do you need one csv with all objects, or one for each type? What Computer object fields do you need?

Comment: For one thing, `Get-ADGroupMember` can return objects of type 'user', 'computer' and/or 'group', so after that you need to loop over the collection and check the objects `.objectClass` property. If this is 'user' you can use `Get-ADUser`. For a  'computer' you need `Get-ADComputer`. If it is a 'group' you can decide to ignore it or recurse the code to get users and computers from child groups. That said, Your output defines fields present in a users properties, but a computer has different properties, so if they don't match you will end up with a csv with lots of empty (not available) fields..

Answer (score 0):

Just test for the objectclass and deal with accordingly. Use a custom object to construct the output.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'TST*'"
$groups | ForEach-Object {
    $Results = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_  | ForEach-Object {
    #
    # For each objectclass you must output the same properties else
    # the custom PS object will not construct across object types
    # I find this the best way to make it obvious what your code is doing:
    #
        If ($_.objectclass -eq 'user') {
            $ObjDetails = Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties mail,AccountExpires,manager,employeeid,employeetype
            $Mail = $ObjDetails.mail
            $EmployeeID = $ObjDetails.employeeid
            $EmployeeType = $ObjDetails.employeetype
        # Unless you're SURE all these fields are populated correctly use Try...Catch or test for the field before assigning
            Try {
                $ManagerName = (Get-ADuser -identity $ObjDetails.Manager -properties displayname -ErrorAction Stop).DisplayName
            }
            Catch {
                $ManagerName = 'Not found'
            }
        # Not in a User object, but you must define empty fields
            $DNSHostName = ''
        }
        If ($_.objectclass -eq 'computer') {
            $ObjDetails = Get-ADComputer -Identity $_ -Properties DNSHostName
        # These fields are not in a Computer object but you must define them
            $Mail = ''
            $EmployeeID = ''
            $EmployeeType = ''
            $ManagerName = ''
        # This field unique to computer object
            $DNSHostName = $ObjDetails.DNSHostName
        }
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SamAccountName = $ObjDetails.SamAccountName
            Mail = $Mail
            EmployeeID = $EmployeeID
            EmployeeType = $EmployeeType
            ManagerName = $ManagerName
            DNSHostName = $DNSHostName
        }
    }
    # You can then display/export results object
    $Results # | Export-CSV -Path "C:\tmp\$($group.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: thanks but I am getting an error message like below. `Export-CSV : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less 
than 248 characters.`

Comment: Then use a shorter path name? You're missing a backslash too - should be C:\tmp\$($group.Name).csv